# Django template code not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I already defined a handler for "get_list" but whenever I run this AJAX code, the terminal does not show that I have called this "get_list" function. Please help.

```
<script>
    function update_list() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/get_list/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $.cookie("csrftoken"), 'type': 'open'},
        success: function(data) {
          alert("PUSHED")
          $('.ticketList').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      update_list();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure, you have right URL dispatcher configured for this url?
And, please check if update_list is launching with debug or console.log.

Comment: My url config is `url(r'^get_list/$', views.get_list, name='get_list')` @amureki

Comment: @amureki I tested getting the view using the url and it works. It is just that the ajax doesn't even call the function on the server (the request doesn't show up on my main console)

Comment: That's why I've asked you to check if update_list() is launching. Like before ajax call write console.log(123) and check developer console for '123' text'.

Comment: @amureki it isn't launching suddenly. It was just now though.

Comment: So it works? You should also consider throwing in a `error:` param in there to see any issues.